# What is the simple way to run a non-blocking coroutine?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

In Go language, running another task in non-blocking way is pretty simple.

```golang
import "net/http"

func Call(request http.Request) http.Response {
    response := getResponse(request)
    go doTask(request)  // Non-blocking. No need to wait for result.
    return response
}

func getResponse(request http.Request) http.Response {
    // Do something synchronously here
    return http.Response{}
}

func doTask(r http.Request) {
    // Some task which takes time to finish
}
```

How can I achieve this in python?

I tried like this:

```py
import asyncio
import threading
from asyncio.events import AbstractEventLoop

loop: AbstractEventLoop

def initialize():
    global loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_event_loop)
    thread.start()

def run_event_loop():
    loop.run_forever()

def call(request):
    response = get_response(request)

    # This should not block
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(do_task(request), loop)

    return response

def get_response(r):
    # Do something synchronously here
    return 42

async def do_task(r):
    # Some task which takes time to finish
    return
```

This works, but it is kind of cumbersome.

Besides, the python code only make use of *one* thread for tasks, while Go automatically dispatches tasks to multiple processes (and so does Kotlin).

Is there better way?

Comment: If you need to run a non-blocking coroutine, you can simply use `asyncio.create_task(coroutine())`. This assumes that you are running in the event loop thread, which is how a program that uses asyncio is supposed to be structured.

Comment: The thread is not necessarily event loop thread, so I cannot simply use `create_task`. I guess `loop.run_in_executor` is so far the best option I can choose.

Comment: Do you even need asyncio, and async in general? If all you want is to call sync functions without waiting for them to complete, `concurrent.futures` is a much simpler way to accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 0):

We can run non-blocking tasks by using the `concurrent.futures` module. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` object is used for this purpose. You could modify your code to use this approach by making the following adjustments:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def call(request):
    response = get_response(request)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
        e.submit(do_task)

    return response

def get_response(r):
    # Do something synchronously here
    return 42

async def do_task(r):
    # Some task which takes time to finish
    return
```

`response` would be returned instantly and `do_task` would run after the result is returned.